# \dot not centred above \symbf of a capital letter

Tags: fonts, xetex, tex-gyre-math

Using TeX Gyre Pagella as my maths font, the "fluxion" dot is not centred properly above capital bold-faced Latin symbols.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}

\begin{document}
How to centre the dot over the character?  $\dot\symbf{x}$ works but $\dot\symbf{X}$ does not.

The same happens if displayed:
\begin{displaymath}
\dot\symbf{X} \qquad \dot\symbf{x}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `\setmathfont` line, then things work.  I'm compiling with an up-to-date TL 2016 distribution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `\dot\mathbf{X}`. By the way: `unicode-math` must be loaded before `setmainfont` ...

Comment: Oops, yes, that was me reordering the MWE :)  It's in the right order in the original file.  I was under the impression that `\mathbf` was deprecated for `\symbf`...

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill You're right using `\symbf` in this case; `\mathbf` does a different thing. It seems like a bug in the Pagella Math font, because it happens with both LuaTeX and XeTeX. If I use Termes Math or Asana Math the output is as expected. Anyway, correct input should be `\dot{\symbf{x}}`

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: `\mathbf` is not deprecated, it has another meaning! You are using Pagella for text and math the reason why it should make no difference here.

Answer (score 10):

The affected characters seem to be D, X and Y. It's a bug in the font, as it happens both with LuaTeX and XeLaTeX, but not with other math fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
%\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}
How to centre the dot over the character?  $\dot{\symbf{x}}$ works but $\dot{\symbf{X}}$ does not.

\count255=\numexpr`A-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
\advance\count255 1
$\dot{\symbf{\Uchar\count255}}$
\repeat

\count255=\numexpr`A-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
\advance\count255 1
$\acute{\symbf{\Uchar\count255}}$
\repeat

\count255=\numexpr`A-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`Z
\advance\count255 1
$\mathring{\symbf{\Uchar\count255}}$
\repeat

\count255=\numexpr`a-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`z
\advance\count255 1
$\dot{\symbf{\Uchar\count255}}$
\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with Asana Math

[image]

A workaround might be to add

```
\setmathfont[range=\symbf]{Asana Math}
```

Comment: Who will (or already did) sent the bug report?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know who to contact?

Comment: I would have tried the mail address from here http://www.gust.org.pl/contact-info/